# Well Plumbing question

Tags: plumbing

I want to run a line from well to house at approx 150'   Can I run a 1 1/2" pipe within a 4" conduit or  4" pipe as a safety measure for future in case I need to run a new pipe or when the original fails.

Comment: You can, but what in heck are you expecting? Quality polyethylene well pipe can be had long enough that there are no joints to fail, and has a service life greater than 50 years. If in doubt, move to a higher pressure class (i.e. use 200 PSI pipe, not 160 or 100 PSI pipe.) The only place I bother with a sleeve is where it's crossing a driveway. Wire, on the other hand, should be in conduit, not direct burial.

Comment: I have to upvote ecnerwal but would say 40 years as recently several homes I built have had failures, I believe in all the cases were from ground movement from cutting down trees were more the cause than the age of the poly, the galvanized we put in when dad was still alive failed years ago,   how the heck did they find me I live in another state now?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are many regulations about buried water pipe. Best practice in most areas is at least 18" from the top of the pipe, to the top of the ditch.   You  are definitely future proofing your install, but getting a second pipe of same size will be a very snug fit and probably logistically challenging. It's also very unlikely for a pipe to "fail" unless mechanically damaged.  Once in a while a coupling will fail and start leaking if it wasn't glued up well.   But those can be found (think wet spots!), dug up and repaired. Same with mechanical damage.  Surely protecting the 1.5" pipe inside a 4" would vastly minimize the chances of  mechanical damage.   But if you are so concerned about it, why not just run 2 1.5" pipes now? 4" pipe would be quite expensive and hard to install the 2nd line at a later date.   BTW, what type of pipe? PVC? Poly?   One more thing: If PVC, you could run schedule 80, which is pretty tough stuff.

Comment: Please contemplate considering frost-line depth. 18" would not be a good idea at all where I live....

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thanks for the comment, good advice. Here in western Washington, freezing down to 18" would mean  Armageddon or the 2nd coming!   I forget that many parts of the country have very cold winters that last a long time. Thanks for your input.

Comment: George I understand what you are saying for the PNW + but poly is the best it flexes with earth movement for this area, the more rigid the pipe the shorter it’s life in my experience and most the failures have been after tree removal or earthquakes but a few from roots, an outer conduit or parallel line won’t help in those cases and saving those $ for the future would probably be best in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I understand and agree with George’s answer for the PNW it doesn’t get cold enough for long enough to freeze pipes below 18” here.

What will happen is dirt ends getting in the 4” conduit over the years and even pull soap alone can make a 150’ run almost impossible to remove wires from a conduit ,,, a poly pipe would be ripped apart from a dried out lubricant and or dirt if the pipe when it fails.

The cost of a larger 4”  “conduit” to pull the pipe would not be a wise expenditure today.  if you put that $ in a gold / silver coins even at our low interest rates today it would more than pay for a new line to be installed in 40 or 50 years.

I base this from an economics class in college that the prof said a gold coin in the time of Christ was enough to buy a nice suit, at that time a gold coin would buy a nice suit , today a gold coin will still buy a nice suit, not trying to equate anything more than over time an ounce of gold has been somewhat constant.with that the large conduit will cost more than trenching and replacing the poly pipe.